# Can I set an anchor when I use CIFilter to scale video or image?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, cifilter, scaletransform

Here is my code;

```
_coreImageFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBicubicScaleTransform"];    
[_coreImageFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[_coreImageFilter setValue:@2 forKey:kCIInputScaleKey];
```

But this scale started at point (0, 0). Can i set an anchor or center to scale it from the center?

Comment: Can you apply a CIAffineTransform to translate the image so anchor point is at (0,0), apply scale transform and then apply another CIAffineTransform to translate back

Comment: @Spads Yes,that's what i did.But i wonder if there is a better way to deal with this